# Eclipse two duplicate consoles, can't delete only one -- Luna SR 2 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse

Used Eclipse for many years for Java and pretty sure I have had this in the previous and maybe earlier releases.  I've searched multiple terms on the web, like `eclipse duplicate consoles` and `eclipse too many consoles` and `eclipse two consoles` and `eclipse extra console`, sometimes with a phrase quoted, but nothing is applicable.

In Eclipse Luna Service Release 2, 4.4.2, two console tabs appear with identical content, in the same subwindow.  When I delete (close, X) one, they both go away.  Then when I Run the program again both appear.

I am also having duplicate Package Explorers and Project Explorers.

I only want and need one of each, since tab space is at a premium sometimes.

How can I control this?